# The connection between two theorems in Munkres' book

Tags: general-topology

**(Munkres) Theorem 17.10**: If $X$ is a Hausdorff space, then a sequence of points of $X$ converges to at most one point of $X$.

**(Munkres) Theorem 21.3**: Let $f:X\to Y$. If the function $f$ is continuous, then for every convergent sequence $x_{n}\to x$ in $X$, the sequence $f(x_{n})$ converges to $f(x)$. (...).

What's the connection between them if $Y$ were or were not a Hausdorff space when it comes to sequences?

Comment: It would follow from 21.3 that X has the property that every sequence converges to a single point also, but since 17.10 is not an if and only if, you could not comment on the Hausdorffness of X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that both of these theorems are one-way, in the sense that they do not characterise Hausdorffness or continuity. There are non-Hausdorff spaces where limits of convergent sequences are neverthless unique (so-called UC spaces), and there are sequentially continuous functions between spaces $X$ and $Y$ (i.e. $f$ that satisfy the conclusion of 21.3) that are not continuous.

Theorem 21.3 says nothing about uniqueness of limits in $Y$. It just says that *if* we have a sequence $(x_n)$ and $x$ is a limit of that sequence (there could be more than one, in general!) then $f(x)$ is *a* limit of the sequence $f(x_n)$ (but there could be more). See below for an example.

Now suppose that $f$ is continuous (or sequentially continuous) and $Y$ is Hausdorff, and we have that both $x_1 \neq x_2 \in X$ are limits of a sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$. Then $f(x_n)$ is a sequence with a unique limit, and by 21.3 it must have $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$ as a limit. So $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$. So we get a proposition:

> If $X$ is not UC, $Y$ is Hausdorff, then a sequentially continuous function from $X$ to $Y$ is not injective.

If $Y$ is not Hausdorff there isn't much we can say because 21.3 says that $f(x)$ is just one of the potential limits of $(f(x_n))$, not the unique one. E.g. take any infinite Hausdorff space $X$, let $Y$ be the co-finite topology on that same set. Then any finite to one function $f$ from $X$ to $Y$ is continuous (check inverse image of closed is closed, e.g.) but every non-trivial sequene in $Y$ converges to every point, while limits in $X$ are unique.